# t-sql Parsing 16GB XML file into database

Tags: xml, t-sql, parsing

Recently i managed to parse my first xml file. It was 12 MB. It worked perfectly using that code:

```
DECLARE @DocID INT;
DECLARE @DocXML XML;
SELECT @DocXML = CAST(XMLSource AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\simple1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) 
AS X (XMLSource);

EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @DocID OUTPUT, @DocXML;
```

I put it into variable like that and using 2 cursors i put records to tables row by row.
I tried to apply same method to my new 16 GB file and while doing  `EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @DocID OUTPUT, @DocXML;` i got error like that:

> XML document could not be created because server memory is low. Use
>   sp_xml_removedocument to release XML documents.

What are possible ways to overcome it? Should i use other method of using my XML file without putting it all into memory? Or the only way is to use C# and xmlreader that reads file in parts?

Comment: C# is your best bet in this case

Comment: Yes C# and XmlReader will have the smallest memory.  I don't think there is a SQL fix.  A producer consumer model would be good for parsing and loading concurrently.